# Given matrix $M$, how to find $A$, $B$, $C$ such that $M=ABC$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

My question is actually general: how can one "factorize" a matrix? In particular, given an arbitrary matrix $M$, can one write $$M=ABC$$
for some non-zero matrices $A, B, C$? If yes, is there some way of finding these matrices ("factors")?

EDIT: After reading some nice comments, I present here the conditions on matrices A, B and C, and these are: $A = \sqrt{a}$, $C=\sqrt{c}$ and $B= u v^\dagger$ where $u$ and $v$ are some column vectors and $*$ denotes the combined operation of *complex-conjugation and transposition*.

Comment: There are too many to list here. I would refer you to the wikipedia article on matrix decompositions for more information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition

Comment: The singular value decomposition is a prominent example, this decomposition always exists.

Comment: Let $A$ and $C$ be any invertible matrices and let $B = A^{-1}MC^{-1}$. This will rarely be useful.

Comment: Well, you can take any two of $A$, $B$ and $C$ to be $I$ and the other one to be $M$. The question only becomes interesting if you impose some constraints on $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @RobArthan love the simplicity of this answer

Comment: @RobArthan, you got it absolutely right! My actual question indeed has some conditions on A,B,C which I have now mentioned in the EDIT.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Matrices?

Comment: Only constraints on a and b is that they are positive.